# Attach Android Device on Linux for Debugging

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I am trying to connect my android phone (Qmobile) with Linux mint but its not appearing in eclipse.. Actually i was appearing as unknown device before but i tried some commands from internet it is disappeared now :( can anyone help me how to connect Android phone with Linux for debugging with eclipse.
i used following commands in terminal before:
adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
 Kindly Answer me if you can Thanks.

Comment: Type in 'adb devices' and see if it's detected

Comment: Intsab-Latitude-3540 Intsab # adb devices
List of devices attached 

Intsab-Latitude-3540 Intsab #

Comment: So the list of devices is empty? or is that your devices id?